# Is there a reason titles sound better using 'of' instead of without 'of'?

Tags: word-order, titles

For popular media, it's common to use X of Y in the title. Examples: Call of Duty, God of War, World of Warcraft, and so on.

In theory, these could be Duty Call, War God, or Warcraft World, right? Is it haphazard preference or is there a hidden reason that causes rearranging words and inserting 'of' to sound better?

Apologies if this has already been asked. I searched but didn't find any existing discussion.

Comment: Not just popular media - most formal titles are traditionally in this form (King of England, Duke of Norfolk etc.)

Comment: There's also lots of titles like The Horse Whisperer, Star Wars, Iron Man, Wonder Woman, Speed Racer, Kindergarten Cop, The Night Stalker, Ghostbusters, etc. Could be Whisperer of Horses, Man of Iron, Cop of the Kindergarten, Woman of Wonder, Stalker of the Night, etc, but they're not. It probably depends on the individual sound of the different phrases and personal preference.